# How to give condition on compressing the file with tar -cvf

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

If I want to compress the file with `tar -cvf`, is there any option to give a condition like the following?

> disk 0 : /centos/user0 - 15G available
> disk 1 : /centos/user1 - 1G abailable

```
cd /centos/user0/
 
tar -cvf /centos/user1/test01.tar *
```

Since `/centos/user1` has small disk space available, I want to stop compressing if the available disk space of `/centos/user1` becomes less than 300M.

Is there any option like this on `tar` function?
Or is there any way to do like this?

Comment: note that `tar -cvf` doesn't compress anything, it just combines them into an archive. a compressor like gzip or xz can compress the resulting archive. if you're operating under limited disk space, this can help

Comment: Oh! I misput the words. Yes, that's right. I really need to make light script which does not give any pressure on CPU, so I need to use tar -cvf for merging files. But the point here is I really want to know how to prevent the disk shortage. Is there any option to stop tar -cvf if the available disk space reaches 300M?

Answer (score 0):

Like most Unix utilities, `tar` implements one functionality, which is creating archives.  It doesn't have functionality to conditionally create archives or to abort on a condition.  The latter would be relatively inefficient in the normal case, since it would likely involve periodically polling an external command.

You could check the size of the data *before* you compress it with `du`, and then determine whether to create the archive at all.  You could also create a background job in a subshell that kills the `tar` process and removes the file if it detects a low amount of disk space.  However, this latter approach might not be fast enough to terminate the operation before running the system out of disk.

Finally, you could create a specific user and add a quota on the small disk, which would prevent the operation from completing if it exceeded the quota.  You'd still have to remove the partial archive, but this would be an effective approach.

Answer (score 0):

My example may not resolve the original issue of this question, however, I want to share the idea of using `tar` with condition indirectly.

1. Create a tar archive:

   ```
   tar cf sample.tar sample.txt
   ```
2. Using the power of the `find` combine with `tar`, for example, adding the CSS file only:

   ```
   find . -name "*.css" -exec tar rf sample.tar {} \;
   ```

   Or adding executable files only:

   ```
   find . -executable -exec tar rf sample.tar {} \;
   ```
3. Checking the archive file:

   ```
   tar tf sample.tar
   ```